# ERROR ON JAVA EMAIL API(The type javax.mail.Authenticator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files)

Tags: java

```
package Hey;

import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;

public class sss {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smpt.gmail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(465);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("oi", "eu"));
}

}
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions?

Answer (score 2):

I may be very wrong but if I had to guess your incorrectly installing the apache commons library what you should do to make sure you get a clean installation is to install maven and if you are using eclipse create a new maven project right click on the pom.xml go to the dependencies tab and add them through that. Or you can download apache-commons through the [website](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons) and with maven installed navigate to the folder with the library and then do `mvn install` after that you should simply be able to create a new maven project via some template online, add the dependencies to that pom.xml and the imports and whatever your doing should work correctly in that project.